# Changing the upload size in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem when uploading image files to my blog. The maximum size stated by Wordpress is 64 MB. However, when I'm trying to upload the message shows that:

> files over 500 KB are not allowed

You can see the issue in the image attached.

[image: the image that shows the issue]

Comment: It seems like some people using WooCommerce are having this problem. Are you using WooCommerce?

Comment: No, I'm not using WooCommerce. Thanks

Comment: what is `multi file uploader` in your wesite? is it some plugin or theme feature ?

Comment: If it is apache, check in PHP.ini upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300

Comment: I am uploading through the the media library in wordpress. However, I am using a theme that I installed separately.

Comment: I checked the php.ini and all seems ok:
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300

Answer (score 0):

First Go to Your Hosting Cpanel. 
Then Go PHP Vertions:

[image]

Click to switch to PHP options:

[image]

After Click Show this page You can change you upload size here By click there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I could only change the php version, but not the options. The panel looks a bit different in your image from mine. I'm using cPanel version  68.0.29